# Why is kafkaUtils.createStream() throwing me errors?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I am trying to connect Spark to Apache Kafka. I am using this below mentioned code to connect but I am getting error. I request someone to tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from uuid import uuid1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreaming")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2) # 2 second window
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, \
                                  "localhost:9092", \
                                  "test",\
                                  {test:1})
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am getting this error

> NameError: name 'test' is not defined

while `test` is indeed the name of my topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to display the list of Topics by using of following command and make sure that topic is available .

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```